Unable to login with newly created user after installing Oracle 19c
I have been struggling with this since 2 days. Not able to understand why I am not able to login in sqlplus with the created user. Please find the sequence of steps below which I am following.
Also please note that I have just installed Oracle 19c in my Windows machine.
C:\Users\frank>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Sep 1 20:35:21 2024
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;

Session altered.

SQL> create user test_user_dba identified by london01;

User created.

SQL> GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO test_user_dba;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant all privileges to test_user_dba;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

C:\Users\frank>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun Sep 1 20:37:14 2024
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: test_user_dba
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied 

Any help or Pointers would be a Great help.
I have already googled this but didn't find any relevant issue or solution anywhere.

I'm not sure exactly where things are going wrong with your steps, but there is likely (and understandably) a lot of confusion going on with OS versus database authentication, and container database (CDB) versus pluggable database (PDB).
The command alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true; means that you are using old or broken instructions. That undocumented parameter is almost never needed, unless you are logging into the wrong database. To avoid confusion, you should always explicitly use a connection string, for example, sqlplus /@orcl as sysdba for the CDB and sqlplus /@orclpdb as sysdba for the PDB. (Or whatever your connections strings are named.)
If you are using a multi-tenant Oracle database, you need to read up about PDB and CDB. You have two databases to worry about, whether you like it or not. So make sure you are using the appropriate documentation. If you do not have a multi-tenant database, then you are definitely using the wrong instructions.

I tried with the above but none of the connection is working. SQL>  select dbid, con_id, name from v$pdbs;
  DBID     CON_ID


NAME
750828266          2
PDB$SEED
1187885542          3
ORCLPDB
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
C:\Users\devashish>sqlplus /@orclpdb as sysdba
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

@etlzone9 If you only see one row in V$PDBS from the root container, that implies that you have no created any pluggable databases. You might want to re-run the DBCA utility and ask it to create a pluggable database for you by selecting the option "Manager Pluggable databases". I think it will automatically add a PDB, service, tns entry, etc. Keep track of the service names. If you've lost them, run tinsping orcl to find the directory that contains the file sqlnet.ora, and tnsnames.ora should be in the same place. Realistically, you might want to fully re-install with all defaults.

Based on your comment, you are getting ORA-12154
C:\Users\devashish>sqlplus /@orclpdb as sysdba 
ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

You could try to use tnsping <IP address of 19c DB> if tnsping orclpdb fails
when testing the connection.
You could try this also (assuming the PDB is already open)
C:\Users\frank>sqlplus sys@orclpdb as sysdba

Just wondering, are these two users on the same computer?
